# What is the fastest way to extract the page source using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application that needs to extract html code from a webpage using python with selenium. The call browser.page_source takes about 0.10s for a page containing about 1MB html code.  I would like to do this in the most efficient way. I am stuck with selenium since the whole application is built up around that, and the page also contains some dynamically updated data.
I have tried using selenium with both Firefox and Chrome. Firefox seems to be slightly faster than Chrome (of the order of a few hundreds of a second) when running with the standard settings.
I was wondering if anyone has experience playing with the browser settings in selenium to optimise the time it takes to get the page source?

Comment: Still haven't found a way to speed things up, any suggestions are more than welcome!

Answer (score -1):

You can consider 2 options,

1. **Selenium headless mode.**

   ```
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument("--headless")
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
   ```
2. try to inject BS4 (Beautiful soup) to extract information.

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and
> XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic
> ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It
> commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.

read more about [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Using **BS4 :**

```
html_content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
```

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, I am already using beautiful soup for the html-parsing, is it also possible to use beautiful soup for extracting html from a selenium browser object?

Comment: @Per : yes using selenium driver you can get the page resource and then pass the reference in BeautifulSoup like above. I have updated the post above.

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, as explained in the original post it is simply the call browser.page_source I would like to speed up, the parsing of the html using beautifulsoup only takes a fraction of the time the page_source call takes. Any suggestions on modifying the browser settings to improve the speed for the "page_source" call very welcome. I have tried headless mode, initially it looked promising, but after looking at it in more detail headless mode does not seem to speed up the call to the page source.

Comment: See the `speed BS4 > headless selenium > Selenium browser ` bs4 is fastest among all

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, how can I force to use BS4 in this call "html_content = driver.page_source"? Again, it is not about improving the speed of the parsing of the html, but simply improving the time it takes to extract the html from the webdriver.

Comment: `driver.page_source` how much time does it take ?

Comment: as written in original post it takes about 0.10s, for a page containing about 1MB of html data. It is this time I would like to reduce.

Comment: I am not sure about this, cause for me in general it takes like 2-3 seconds to give me page resource, and often I have been okay with that.

Comment: Any new suggestions here?